# Remove double quotes in python pandas for all column's values

Tags: python, csv, pandas

so I am reading a CSV file and then only keeping certain columns and rewriting the file. The issues I have is that one column (say ColumnA) has it's values in double quotation marks. Is there an easy way for me to achieve this task and also remove those double quotes?

```
a = pd.read_csv(filename,low_memory=False)

a1 = a[['ColumnA','ColumnB']]

a1.to_csv('filelocation')
```

Comment: try `df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].str.replace('"','')`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw data, also if you only intend to load those columns you can specify this in `read_csv`:  `a = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['ColumnA','ColumnB'])`

Comment: i added that line before "a1 = ..." statement but it didn't work...

Comment: Your column names may not be what you think they are then, again I ask you to post a sample of the raw data

Comment: your solution worked. thank you

Comment: Sorry what worked exactly? you mean this: `df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].str.replace('"','')`?

Answer (score 6):

you can suppress quoting using `csv.QUOTE_NONE`:

```
import csv
pd.read_csv(filename,usecols=['ColumnA','ColumnB']) \
  .to_csv(new_file_name, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index=False)
```

but it's better (safer) to chose another delimiter (the one which doesn't occur in the `ColumnA` column), so you won't have problems in future when you will read/parse that new CSV file:

```
pd.read_csv(filename,usecols=['ColumnA','ColumnB']) \
  .to_csv(new_file_name, sep=';', index=False)
```